# What does "吹" in "她在冷风中吹了好一会儿" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I could not determine which one the "吹" in this sentence means.

From what I understand, it generally means "blow" and "fail"

我们吹了= We broke up (fail)

他吹了一声口哨= He whistles (blow)

Then it could also mean "boast" though I can't find the example.

Answer (score 3):

"吹" roughly means "blow" here, as in "the wind blows". However, as the subject in this sentence is "She", not the cold wind ('冷风'), "吹" can be translated into "to be blown" in a more accurate sense. Similarly, "吹风" can mean either "to blow air" ("disclose information" in extension), or "to be blown by wind", depending on the context.
My translation of "她在冷风中吹了好一会儿” would be "She was exposed in the cold wind for quite a while."

Answer (score 0):

It is "blow".

It seems to be a little weird as "她" is not the subject of blow, but the object. In Chinese, there is the "[topic-comment](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Topic-comment_sentences)" structure, where the "topic", instead of the subject, is put at the beginning of the sentence. And the topic may be object of the verb.

Other examples:

> **作业**做完了
>
> (I) have finished the **homework**.

Answer (score 0):

> 她在冷风中吹了好一会儿

We need more context to determine the meaning here.  Stand alone, it could mean:

1. she was blown by the chilly wind for quite a while.
2. she whistled in the chilly  wind for quite a while.
3. she played some sort of instrument (that required blowing e.g. saxophone) in the chilly  wind for quite a while.
4. （something else needs 吹）

Answer (score 0):

My take is, unless the specific context is available, she  is either whistling or blowing some musical instrument in the cold wind.

My reason is that if she was just being blown by the cold wind, the sentence would have been -- 她*被*冷风吹了好一会儿, (the 中 is also omitted)

Therefore, the 在 and the 中 gives the idea that she is *doing something in the midst of* the cold wind.

Finally, let's take away 在冷风中, and we will get 她.....吹了好一会儿, -- "she....*blow* or *whistle* for quite awhile"

Answer (score 0):

她在冷风中吹了好一会儿。  (她被冷风吹了好一会儿。)
The cold breeze blew down on her quite a while.

车没来。
The bus didn't come.

她决定去车站的另一端。
She decided to stand on the other side of the bus stop.